# Performing an action on end editing

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, nstextfield

I have a text field in my Objective-C Mac app.

This is what I want: when I stop writing in the text field for more than 5 seconds, it runs something. Is this possible?

If so, can someone explain how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Make sure your text field’s continuous option is turned on.
2. Connect the text field’s delegate to your controller.
3. Implement `controlTextDidChange:` in your controller.
4. Start a timer (and invalidate the old one) each time you receive `controlTextDidChange:`.

Here’s an example:

```
- (void)controlTextDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification
{
   if (timeoutTimer != nil) {
      [timeoutTimer invalidate];
      [timeoutTimer release];
      timeoutTimer = nil;
   }

   timeoutTimer = [[NSTimer 
      scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0
      target:self
      selector:@selector(doSomething)
      userInfo:nil
      repeats:NO] retain];
}
```

Comment: The docs: ["NSTextFieldDelegates For Fun and Profit"](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSTextFieldDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html), ["What the heck is Delegation, Anyways?"](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH14-SW1), and, ["What Does My Control's Delegate Do All Day?"](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ControlCell/Tasks/ValidatingControlEntries.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000070-BCIBIJEJ).

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm being a complete newbie at this, but can you please direct me to a place that explains how to implement things into a controller?

Comment: And connecting my text fields delegate to the controller?

Comment: Try just pasting that code somewhere in your controller class’ implementation (which is the file ending in “.m”). To make your controller the delegate for the text field, right click and drag from the text field to your controller in Interface Builder. Choose `delegate` when it asks which outlet to connect.

Answer (score 1):

Use `-performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`, and cancel the perform request if the user begins typing again. Here's a crude example:

```
- ( void )controlTextDidChange: (NSNotification *)notification
{
    if ( [ notification object ] != myTextField ) {
        return;
    }

    [ NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget: self
               selector: @selector( userStoppedEditing: )
               object: myTextField ];
    [ self performSelector: @selector( userStoppedEditing: )
           withObject: myTextField
           afterDelay: 5.0 ];
}
```